# Cisco ASA 5505 with separate subnets and separate ISPs

Tags: cisco-asa

I am trying to join two networks together thru the ASA.

I have a 192.168.0.1 network that is the main domain and has its own ISP and is administered by Windows Server 2008 for DNS and DHCP.

I also have a separate network with 4 PCs on a different network with a 192.168.4.1 with its own ISP and is hooked into a Linksys router.

I am new to this but I need the .4 to access some shared drives on the .0. I have tried static routing on both the ASA and the Linksys router. I cannot get them to see each other thru ping but the ARP table in the ASA shows the .4 subnet. I am at a loss and my of given too much info or not enough. Any help is greatly appreciated.

I changed the subnet to 255.255.0.0 and it worked, but I lost some device connectivity on the main network. Could I add a second IP address to the NIC in the .4 subnet to access the .0? Would that cause an issue?

Comment: In same site or not, we miss that info. If same site its more routing, if not, then site to site vpn is your answer

Comment: Its all on the same site

Comment: Why you dont mix them then with a 255.255.0.0 subnet mask

Comment: I thought about that. Didn't want to have to change all the netowrk settings on all the static devices. Hoping I could route the traffic thru the asa to do it for me

Comment: hmm, not a god idea if you can use the computer in the lan directly with the new mask, why you would told me, because the fileshare traffic will go througth a giga switch, not on your 100mbits interface that have already internet traffic

Comment: so changing my subnets to 255.255.0.0 on all devices will allow me to mix the subnets... do i need to change this subnet on my dhcp server in windows 2008 also.. never done it before so want to make sure i have all changes made so i dont have any undue down time.. thanks for your help

Comment: another implication is that i have an asterisk phone server running on the .0 network .. not sure what changing subnet mask would do to the phones ...

Comment: They need to be on same switch, yes you need to change the dhcp server. For the pbx or phone system if you dont change it it will only does not talk to the other host.

Answer (score 1):

Cisco ASA has something called security levels, traffic from high level to low level is allowed by default, but you have to configure ACLs to allow traffic to come back. On the other hand, you can configure CBAC on ASA.

Comment: What is CBAC? Sorry I am very new to the ASA..

Comment: CBAC is also a kind of ACL, but it is more flexible than ACLs.

Comment: What rules would i need to implement?

Comment: It depends on your requirements. If you just want to ping successfully, just allow icmp

Comment: need toaccess a shared drive on the .0 domain...